# can't bind parameters in mybatis foreach

Tags: java, foreach, mybatis

i'm trying to bind multiple parameters in mybatis foreach which worked fine last night.
here is my code

```
<insert id="insertWbs" parameterType="HashMap"> 
    <if test="paramList.size != 0">
        BEGIN
            <foreach collection="paramList" item="item" separator=";">
                insert into wbs(proj_no, task_name, wbs_worker, wbs_tester, wbs_ex_start, wbs_ex_end, wbs_unique, task_status, wbs_parent)
                    select #{item.proj_no}, #{item.task_name}, #{item.wbs_worker}, #{item.wbs_tester}, to_date(#{item.wbs_ex_start}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date(#{item.wbs_ex_end}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), #{wbs_unique}, #{item.task_status}, #{item.wbs_parent} from dual where not exists
                    (select wbs_unique from wbs where wbs_unique = #{wbs_unique})
            </foreach>;
        END;
    </if>
</insert>
```

as you guys see the parameter type is HashMap and the collection paramList is one of the key in the map.

and now this code throws error like this

```
There is no getter for property named 'proj_no' in 'class java.lang.String'
```

strange thing is that it worked fine last night. even the code which runs on same logic is still working fine.

```
<update id="updateWbs" parameterType="HashMap">
    <if test="paramList.size != 0">
    BEGIN
        <foreach collection="paramList" item="item" separator=";">
            <if test="#{item.wbs_start} != null and #{item.wbs_end} != null">
                update wbs set task_name = #{item.task_name}, wbs_worker = #{item.wbs_worker}, wbs_tester = #{item.wbs_tester}, task_status = #{item.task_status}, wbs_start = to_date(#{item.wbs_start}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), wbs_end = to_date(#{item.wbs_end}, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
                where wbs_unique = #{item.wbs_unique} 
            </if>

            <if test="#{item.wbs_start} != null and #{item.wbs_end} == null">
                update wbs set task_name = #{item.task_name}, wbs_worker = #{item.wbs_worker}, wbs_tester = #{item.wbs_tester}, task_status = #{item.task_status}, wbs_start = to_date(#{item.wbs_start}, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
                where wbs_unique = #{item.wbs_unique} 
            </if>

            <if test="#{item.wbs_start} == null and #{item.wbs_end} != null">
                update wbs set task_name = #{item.task_name}, wbs_worker = #{item.wbs_worker}, wbs_tester = #{item.wbs_tester}, task_status = #{item.task_status}, wbs_end = to_date(#{item.wbs_end}, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
                where wbs_unique = #{item.wbs_unique} 
            </if>

            <if test="#{item.wbs_start} == null and #{item.wbs_end} == null">
                update wbs set task_name = #{item.task_name}, wbs_worker = #{item.wbs_worker}, wbs_tester = #{item.wbs_tester}, task_status = #{item.task_status}    
                where wbs_unique = #{item.wbs_unique} 
            </if>
        </foreach>;
    END;
    </if>
</update>
```

i really don't know what i missed. 
i've tried everything i can..
please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This query will work if you pass correct objects in the map (that is objects that have properties that are used in the query) but will not work if you pass the map with wrong object type. You probably put a String into the map that is passed to the query.

Comment: i fixed it. the difference between my queries was that the collection paramList of the first one is Map<String, Object> and the other one is List<Map<String, Object>>. after i change the parameter as List<Map<String, Object>>, it works fine. but i still don't get it why i can't use the Map<String, Object>. would you please explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

According to mybatis [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach):

> When using a Map (or Collection of Map.Entry objects), index will be
>   the key object and item will be the value object

It means that when you pass the map as an argument to `foreach` then the loop will be over map values. In your case you must have keys `proj_no`, `task_name` etc with values that are strings:

```
{
  'proj_no' -> 'some-project-number',
  'task_name' -> 'some-task-name',
  // and so on
}
```

If you pass `Map` to `foreach` then `item` will have `some-project-number` in the first iteration, `some-task-name` on the second and so on. `#{item.proj_no}` tries to get a property from that object with name `proj_no`. And because it is a string it can't find out and shows that in the error message.

Your code would work if you pass a `List` that contains a `Map` with keys `proj_no`, `task_name` etc. because in that case `item` in the `foreach` loop will be the whole map. If you need to pass just single map you don't need `foreach`, do like this:

```
<insert id="insertWbs" parameterType="HashMap"> 
    insert into wbs(proj_no, task_name, wbs_worker, wbs_tester, wbs_ex_start, wbs_ex_end, wbs_unique, task_status, wbs_parent)
                select #{paramList.proj_no}, #{paramList.task_name}, #{paramList.wbs_worker}, #{paramList.wbs_tester}, to_date(#{paramList.wbs_ex_start}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date(#{paramList.wbs_ex_end}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), #{wbs_unique}, #{paramList.task_status}, #{paramList.wbs_parent} from dual where not exists
                (select wbs_unique from wbs where wbs_unique = #{wbs_unique})
</insert>
```